# How to keep track and version your binary assets while keeping them outside of git/mircurial

Tags: git, binary, controls, version, assets

I'm starting up a project using git or mercurial and I know that binary assets (art and non code) have the possibility of bloating the repository above a gig or two slowing it down and hitting many free services 2 gig cap.

I'm wondering, whats the best way to track these art+/binary assets and keep track of which set (if they were say backed up in zipped files on drop box) goes with which commit.  Perforce is an option but short of buying a cheep VPN for this project, self hosting it sounds like a extra pain even though the repository I hear can hold many gigs well with the 20/20 free plan.

What are some viable ways to track binary data usefully so it can be used with your versioned code?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/);

> "git-annex allows managing files with git, without checking the file contents into git."